# How to avoid sendKeys method in selenium to clear previously filled text?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, appium

The android application that I'm testing using Appium with Java has the tag/mention users feature. Now I want to test this feature. I'd like to send multiple mentions and verify that the mentions are sent or not. The application that I'm testing is similar to slack/messaging application.

**Test case steps**:

1. Open chatroom
2. Tap on send message field to activate the keyboard
3. Type @ and wait for list of users to tag/mention appear
4. Tap user 1
5. Send a space after the user1 is tagged/mentioned
6. Type @ again and wait for list of users to tag/mention appear
7. Tap user 2
8. Tap message send button

I'm using page object model. So to perform the above steps I created a method named sendMultiMention in the page class as follows:

```
@Override
public ChatroomPage sendMultiMention(int index0, int index1){
    sendKeyToElement(SENDMESSAGEFIELD, "@");
    List<MobileElement> mentionPersonNamesList = 
    waitAndReturnElementListIfDisplayed(MENTIONPERSONNAME);
    MobileElement mentionPersonNameSelect0 = mentionPersonNamesList.get(index0);
    tapOnElement(mentionPersonNameSelect0);
    sendKeyToElement(SENDMESSAGEFIELD, "@");
    MobileElement mentionPersonNameSelect1 = mentionPersonNamesList.get(index1);
    tapOnElement(mentionPersonNameSelect1);
    tapOnElement(SENDMESSAGEBUTTON);
    return this;
}
```

So the problem with the above code is the 2nd sendKeytoElement overwrites (i.e. clears) the previously filled text in the send message text field.

So what it does is the following:
types @ -> selects user1 -> clears @user1 ->types @ again -> selects @user2.

But what I want is to do the following:
types @ -> selects user1 -> give a space ->types @ again -> selects @user2

**(i.e. DO NOT CLEAR @user1 FROM THE SEND MESSAGE TEXT FIELD)**

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: sendkeys will always clear existing text. Try getting the current text first and then add them to the string you want to type.

Comment: Hi @Naveen - I have also tried that out. The problem with this course of action is that it removes the link of the mentioned users profile and just sendKeys as plain text.

Comment: Which appium version are you using? Try using latest version of appium. Its working fine for java-client 7.0.0.

Comment: Hi @SubanDhyako - I'm using java-client version 7.3.0. I'm also using Appium server 1.16. These are the latest out there in the maven central repos and Appium site.